# Need calculate number with two conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns, measure

I have table:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFKWT.png)

There was a need to count the number of stores under two conditions.

1. There are 2/3/4 necessary SKUs in the store
2. The amount of sales in the store is more than $30

for example, I need to find a store that sells $30 or more and has SKU1 and SKU2

In this case, the answer will be "3"

If you need to find a store that sells in the amount of $ 30, and where there are SKU1 and SKU4, the answer will be "1

Comment: "Sum" is a Column? or Measure?

Comment: Sum for Shop (column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **measure**:

```
MyMeasure :=
VAR SKU1 = "Sku1"
VAR SKU2 = "Sku4"
VAR MinimumSum = 30
VAR MyTable =
    SUMMARIZE(
        Table1,
        Table1[Shop],
        "Required SKU Count",
            CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( Table1 ), Table1[SKU] = SKU1 )
                * CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( Table1 ), Table1[SKU] = SKU2 ),
        "Shop Sales", SUM( Table1[Sum] )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX( MyTable, ( [Required SKU Count] > 0 ) * ( [Shop Sales] >= MinimumSum ) )
```

Amend the values assigned to the initial parameters *SKU1*, *SKU2* and *MinimumSum* as required.